# WPF/RibbonGallery: Need help understanding binding and events

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, ribbon

i need some help understanding the example posted by [Lester's Blog: Using RibbonGallery Control](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2010/08/19/using-ribbongallery-control.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage). i am relatively new to WPF and not really familiar with MVVM

i dont really understand how the ribbon gallery in the sample is bound and how to handle events like click/selection change to switch the font or color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn MVVM as a start... don't dive in now and regret later when your code will need some maintenance... There are a lot of good tutorials. try this thread:
[MVVM: Tutorial from start to finish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405739/mvvm-tutorial-from-start-to-finish)

Once you get the basics... it will come more natural to you

Comment: erm i am intending to learn MVVM but can this sample be explained in a simple way? like i am not really wanting to make anything big yet, just want to understand the sample abit more.